# Why does the review system disable the "First Posts" and "Late Answers" if I reached daily upvote limit?

Tags: support, review, voting-limits

I was reviewing on [Super User](http://www.superuser.com), and I faced a weird thing. I can review "Close Votes", "Low Quality Posts", and "Suggested Edits" if I reached my daily vote limit, but I can't for "First Posts" and "Late Answers". Why?

[image]

If they just deserve an upvote/downvote then they should not include in the review system. But if we can improve them through leaving comments and by editing the posts then why can't we access them?

Answer (score 19):

I think it is because the **First Posts** and **Late Answers** Review tasks not only allow you to make necessary edits as you see fit, but also upvote and downvote questions or answers which *you wouldn't be able to do if you have reached your vote limit*. You would not be able to effectively review those queues as a result.

**Low Quality Posts**, **Suggested Edits** and **Close Votes** on the other hand, do not require or allow upvoting or downvoting on posts, thus it is still available on your Review tasks.