# Review queues seem to have disappeared

Tags: support, review, top-bar

Today I opened Network Engineering as I do very often, but I noticed a change, which I've not seen before. Normally when I click the review book/list icon I can see the different queues and if any of them needs input. But today I get the message:

> There are no review queues available to you

Here's a screenshot:

[image]

As per request here's the view when I directly open the URL:
https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/review

[image]

I have never seen it like this before.

Is this normal and should I just stop worrying? :-)

Comment: Could you try this link: https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/review and tell us if you're able to access the review queues in this way?

Comment: Will edit with screenshot

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For the First Posts and Late Answers review queues, one of the requirements is that you [need to be able to up-/downvote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/149664/295232). It seems you have used the maximum number of votes today, so you can try again tomorrow.

Comment: Ok thank you i never knew it was like this. I will accept your answer as soon as possible. :-)

Comment: I can understand your confusion; the new review menu is quite new and does not have the room to display the cause.

Comment: Right that's why i noticed it; i normally look at it several times a day, but never after exhausting my votes. Thanks again. :-)

Comment: You're welcome, and thanks for making (Network Engineering) Stack Exchange a better place.