# Vote limit not taken into account for First Answers / First Questions review queue

Tags: bug, review, voting-limits

Upon reaching my vote limit while reviewing Late Answers, I was stopped in my Reviewing tracks by this:

[image]

The same thing used to happen in the old First Posts review queue; see [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149664/why-does-the-review-system-disable-the-first-posts-and-late-answers-if-i-rea) and [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149664/why-does-the-review-system-disable-the-first-posts-and-late-answers-if-i-rea/149669#149669) for argumentation.

However, the new First Answers and First Questions queues do not have this check; I still can't vote, but I can complete the review.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is this a bug or by design? I can review *First Questions* when I’m out of votes, but I can’t review *First Answers* when I’m out of votes.

Comment: It's still a bug, easily reproduced. Until someone on the inside acknowledges otherwise, that's how I see it. There is no logial reason for that inconsistency. One thing I will also add is that when you run out of comment votes, you can still review all of these queues, though I would like to test that bit more, as I've only done that once.