# Disable "First Questions" Queue for those who have spent all their Close Votes

Tags: discussion, review, vote-to-close

When a reviewer has used up their daily close vote quota (50 on SO), the "Close Votes" review queue is no longer available to them and does not show up in the "Review queues" dropdown menu.<sup>1</sup> This is clearly sensible as, for the majority of reviews in that queue, "Close" is the correct action.

However, the "First Question" queue remains accessible. Is this desirable?

In my experience, around 50% of the posts I review in FQ (but don't skip) deserve (and get) a close vote (or a close *flag* for reviewers with < 3k rep.) Should we be allowing reviewers into this queue when such an important ability – casting a close vote/flag – is no longer an option? [This question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/149664/616624) indicates that depleting one's daily quota of **up/down votes** disabled the old "First Posts" queue, but I'm not sure if that's also true for the new, FQ incarnation.

A similar question may apply to the First/Late Answers queues, when a reviewer has depleted their daily flag quota; however, this is perhaps less critical because (in my experience) a significantly lower proportion of posts in those queues warrant an outright NAA or VLQ flag, and skipping those is less of an issue.

---

<sup>1</sup> There is likely a similar limitation on the "Reopen Votes" queue but I have never yet cast 50 reopen votes in a single day.

Comment: Yes, the up/downvote criterion also applies to the new FQ/FA review queues.

Comment: @Glorfindel Then that would reinforce my idea, I think. When in FQ, I cast *far more* close votes than upvotes. ;(